# How to get this visualization in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

[image][image]
I am developing this app.Picture given.
can some one tell me how to get this view (in the two screens back ground image is moving .i.e having markers but the image having trapezoidal blocks are constant in the video ) forming a parallax .

I have put all the files what ever I have tried

PLz help .
Thanks .

There is a class   ViewPagerParallax.java I wont post as it is fine(I guess) and have been taken from 
`https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax` (basically i am modifying the project acc to my need).

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.paraframe;

import com.example.paraframe.ViewPagerParallax;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private static final int MAX_PAGES = 10;

        private static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE = null;

        private int num_pages = 1;   
        private int image=1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.set_max_pages(MAX_PAGES);
            pager.setBackgroundAsset(R.raw.building);
            pager.setAdapter(new my_adapter());

            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i<MAX_PAGES;i++)
            {
                num_pages = Math.min(num_pages+1, MAX_PAGES);
                pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }

            if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
                image=savedInstanceState.getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, R.raw.sanfran);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("Image",image);
            final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            outState.putInt("current_page", pager.getCurrentItem());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.home:
                break;      

            case R.id.landmark:
                break;
            case R.id.futureproof:
                break;
            case R.id.luxury:
                break;
            case R.id.theinsidestory:
                break;
            case R.id.floorplan:
                break;
            case R.id.layout:
                break;             

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private class my_adapter extends PagerAdapter {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return num_pages;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return view == o;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View)object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                View new_view=null;

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                new_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
                ImageView imgPreview=(ImageView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
                imgPreview.setImageResource(R.raw.sanfran);
                container.addView(new_view);
                return new_view;
            }

        }

}
```

This is the layout file, page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.example.paraframe.ViewPagerParallax
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@raw/building" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@raw/sanfran" />
</FrameLayout>

This is activity main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <com.example.paraframe.ViewPagerParallax
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any guess how to solve the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Your page.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@raw/sanfran" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You dont need to add background image to layout it is being added in java code by

```
  pager.setBackgroundAsset(R.raw.building);
```

Comment: it dint work it still shows the blank screen
but by placing image view 2 in main.xml
i can see the stationary screen but the background is missing in this

Comment: why are you using FrameLayout in main.xml ? If you will change it to relative/linear it will work.

Comment: tried with that already no result 
anyway i got the solution there was some declaration error in page.xml
but the biggest worry is both of the images are moving i want only the background to move,not the stationary image (sanfran,jpg)
Any help on that issue???

Comment: On a single screen, image will be stationary but there are more than one screen and when screen changes image(stationary) will come again.Do you want it on a single screen then what about other screens.

Comment: I dint get u keshav
am trying to get the parafllax effect ,so i need the back ground image to be moving but the foreground image to be stationary at one point .
That is what am wondering how to achieve ,
Suppose the background image is there I have given 10 scrolls permission.
so in 10 scrolls it will cover the whole image in background ,but on the top one stationary image will be there,which will be fixed and should not be moving.
is it possible to achieve in one screen ,I dont know so i tried for 2 .
Hope u get my doubt

Comment: Actually there are 10 screen (in your case) so you cant fixed foreground image but you can change that image by another one inside your adapter.But I don't think that you can fix a single image at foreground while background is moving bcoz they are 10 different screens ,its not possible.

Comment: ok still a newcomer ,
help me out I have uploaded two images u can see in both the images on the right bottom part, the image is still while the back ground is moving ,that is what am trying to achieve ,so it will be a parallax
how to achieve that ???